# "to make rapid" - like 'rapidify' or 'rapidise' [sic!]

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word with the meaning that 'rapidise' sounds like it ought to have.

The sentence:

> to make the process more rapid

would be replaced with:

> to rapidise [sic] the process

I have considered

- accelerate
- quicken or hasten
- expedite

which work, but are not *quite* right for me. I'll use 'accelerate' in the absence of anything else, though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes them not *quite* right? Otherwise we'll all just be stumbling around in the dark (also, *quicken* as an adjective usually means "bring to life" or "come alive"; that's the pun in *The Quick and the Dead*: 'cause if you're not quick, you're dead. Get it?)

Comment: At least you're not considering *fasten*.

Comment: What exactly is your specific context? We're likely to speak of *expediting* a potentially long, drawn-out process (such as applying for certain official documents in certain countries). But you'd probably *accelerate* something like the proving of bread dough using yeast, if it was taking too long. Or you might *quicken* your pace if you're not walking fast enough to reach the station before the train leaves. I think the *precise* context is important, since most people probably wouldn't consider those three words idiomatically equivalent and interchangeable in those three contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why "I'll use 'accelerate' in the absence of anything else". Essentially the example sentence - a process, in the context of a task, chore, or job.

Comment: You can consider the phrasal verb *speed up* also but the context is important as always.

Comment: _Speed up_ is the phrasal verb you need.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to suggest "speed up".  "... to speed up the process ..." sounds quite idiomatic to me.

Comment: Did someone try to Americanise your spelling at some point, or is all of that just a preëmptive measure?

Answer (score 3):

If the context is about altering the mechanics of the process so that the goal is achieved more quickly, you can use ***streamline*** or the more generic (but well understood in technology contexts) ***optimize***.

> <sup>[streamline: Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streamline)</sup>
> : to make (something) simpler, more effective, or more productive

> <sup>[optimize: Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optimize)</sup>
> : to make (something) as good or as effective as possible

Comment: 'Streamline' works well, thanks. I don't like 'optimise' as much, since it doesn't alone imply 'for speed'.

Comment: Neither does `streamline`, though

Answer (score 0):

[Dispatch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dispatch) might be the term you're looking for.

**dispatch**: dispose of **rapidly and efficiently**.

*He dispatched the task he was assigned*

Answer (score 0):

You may **expedite** the process.

- Definition: accelerate or speed up the progress of; accomplish
  promptly, as a piece of business.
- Examples: They've asked the judge to expedite the lawsuits. We'll do
  what we can to expedite the processing of your insurance claim.

Comment: As stated in my OP..?